# Find the value of the integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\ln|a+b\sin x|dx$ where $0\lt a\lt b$

Tags: definite-integrals

Find the value of the integral $$\int_0^{2\pi}\ln|a+b\sin x|dx$$ where $0\lt a\lt b$. What is the use of this inequality. I tried to integrate the integral by parts, but the integral of the 2nd term was quite messy.Please help.

Comment: I looks like complex integral could be used here.

Comment: The answer is of the form m(3.141)ln(nb) where m,n are real numbers and mn=1.

Comment: In both cases we have $I=\Re~\bigg\{2\pi\cdot\ln\bigg[\dfrac a2\cdot\bigg(1+\sqrt{1-\dfrac{b^2}{a^2}}~\bigg)\bigg]\bigg\}$.

Comment: Ha! AITS... integer type paper 1.

Comment: @Awesome: Which AITS was it?

Comment: @PranavArora FIITJEE AITS Full Test XI

Comment: Ah, I guessed so, they really ask terrible problems. :D

Comment: @PranavArora You have probably not seen the Open Test conducted by them.

Comment: I have seen most of the papers but not this one. I don't remember much about the Open test, was it too hard? :P

Comment: @PranavArora It is just 4-5 times difficulty level of AITS. This is the paper they prepare for rest of the year.

Comment: @Awesome: Was a solution provided by FIITJEE to this problem?

Comment: @PranavArora No... They are too lazy.

Answer (score 4):

This is just for $0<b < a $

\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^{2\pi}\log(a+\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}+be^{i\theta})d\theta +  \int_0^{2\pi}\log(a+\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}+be^{-i\theta})d\theta\\ 
 &= \int_0^{2\pi} \log \left(2a^2 +2a\sqrt{a^2 - b^2} + (a + \sqrt {a^2 - b^2}) b (e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}) \right )d\theta\\ 
 &= \int_0^{2\pi} \log (2 (a + \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}))d\theta + \int_0^{2\pi }\log(a + b \cos\theta)d\theta\\
\end{align*}

By [Gauss MVT](http://planetmath.org/gaussmeanvaluetheorem), the value of top two integral is 
$$4\pi\log(a + \sqrt{a^2 -b^2})$$
Hence the for $0<b<a$ is 
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \log(a+ b\cos\theta)d\theta = 2 \pi \log \left(a + \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}\over 2\right)$$

EDIT:: The integral for $\log (a + b \sin \theta )$ is equal to that of $\log (a + b \cos \theta )$ as $\theta$ goes around $2 \pi$. It can also be done by changing $be^{-i\theta}$ to $-b e^{-i\theta}$ is above derivation.

For $0<a < b$, the integral is equal to real part of the above solution as mentioned by @Lucian in comments.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{0 < a < b}$.

> \begin{align}
> &\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln\pars{\verts{a + b\sin\pars{x}}}\,\dd x=
> 2\pi\ln\pars{\verts{b}}
> +\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln\pars{\verts{\mu + \sin\pars{x}}}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&\mbox{where}\quad
> \mu \equiv {a \over b}\,,\quad\mbox{Note than}\quad 0 < \mu < 1
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln\pars{\verts{\mu + \sin\pars{x}}}\,\dd x}
=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\ln\pars{\verts{\mu - \sin\pars{x}}}\,\dd x
=\sum_{\sigma = \pm}\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\pars{\verts{\mu + \sigma\sin\pars{x}}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{\sigma = \pm}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}
\ln\pars{\verts{\mu + \sigma\cos\pars{x}}}\,\dd x
=2\sum_{\sigma = \pm}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\ln\pars{\verts{\mu + \sigma\cos\pars{x}}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\verts{\mu - \cos\pars{x}}}\,\dd x
+2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\mu + \cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=2\int_{0}^{\tilde{\mu}}\ln\pars{\cos\pars{x} - \mu}\,\dd x
+2\int^{\pi/2}_{\tilde{\mu}}\ln\pars{\mu - \cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x
+2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\mu + \cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\end{align}
where $\ds{\tilde{\mu} = \arccos\pars{\mu}}$.

> $$
> \color{#c00000}{\!\!\!\!\!\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln\pars{\verts{\mu + \sin\pars{x}}}\,\dd x}
> =
> 2\int_{0}^{\tilde{\mu}}\ln\pars{\cos^{2}\pars{x} - \mu^{2}}\,\dd x
> +2\int^{\pi/2}_{\tilde{\mu}}\ln\pars{\mu^{2} - \cos^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x
> $$

Can you take it from here ?.